# ReactJs useState set array of objects

Tags: reactjs

Im using react functional component with useState.I am trying to update an Array in an Object but its not updating.below is my state

```
const [prodImg, setProdImg] = useState({
    show : false,
    url : '',
    title : '',
    imgList : []
})
```

I want to update `imgList` here by a function which receives an array of objects like below.

```
const setImage = ({ fileList }) => {
    setProdImg(
        {
            ...prodImg,
            imgList: fileList
        },
        console.log(prodImg.imgList)
    )
}
```

here `fileList` is a destructured Array of object.But `prodImg.imgList` is not updating
fileList contains structure like this :

```
[
   {
       name : 'asc.jpg',
   },
   {
       name : 'aqwe.jpg',
   }
]
```

Comment: @rayhatfield to echo, could you place console.log below your useState statement and let us know what it prints after you call the setImage method?

Answer (score 0):

React may [update state asynchronously](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). In your code you just write to console imgList of the current state, which you hold in the stack, but state is actually updated *after* you write it to the console. Try logging the state in the [effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook instead:

```
  const [prodImg, setProdImg] = useState({
    show : false,
    url : '',
    title : '',
    imgList : []
  }) 

  // this callback will be invoked on the component update, eg when state is changed.
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(prodImg.imgList)
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean to *log* the state in the effect?

Comment: It works but useEffect also triggers other functions also

Comment: @kvas, I mean log state in the useEffect hook, see code example.

Comment: @TickTwitch can you please elaborate? I don't quite follow what you mean. useEffect does not trigger anything unless you make something weird inside. It is triggered though on the mount/unmount and update. What exactly is your concern?

Comment: @fenixil I am actually using Upload Component from antd : https://ant.design/components/upload/ . I set `onChange` props to set image files in state and also setting `customRequest` to upload image to cloudinary. but in `customRequest` call i am getting fileLIst empty( even with setTimeout  function call)

Comment: Please provide reproducible example to your question.